# SQL - Inner Join Syntax after the on statement

Tags: mysql

So in my database I have these records that have serial key number to separate them from each other. However I want to join them with another table, where a person can have up to 2 serial numbers associated to their account like so.

```
|account #|Serial#1|Serial#2|
------------------------------------------
|01234201 |P984564|P12388|
------------------------------------------
```

So my question is, can you set up an Inner Join query in the on statement to compare one column against two columns. eg.

`INNER JOIN datatable2 ON datatable1.Serial#1 OR datatabel2.Serial#2 = datatable2.serial#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be:

```
INNER JOIN datatable2 ON datatable1.Serial#1 = datatable2.serial# 
              OR datatable2.Serial#2 = datatable2.serial#
```

I would strongly encourage you to normalize your tables though, so then you don't need an OR condition in your WHERE.

Comment: **if possible.  Sometimes this isn't in fact viable (for example if the database structure is tied to an ERP/CRM/etc).  A secondary suggestion would be to create a view from this and query directly against the normalized view.

Answer (score 1):

Create a normalized `View` for the data and query against that instead.  This will save you some headaches in the future and make your queries more readable.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html for more information on `View`s.  The query associated with your view in particular would be something along the lines of this:

```
  Select AccountNumber, Serial1 as Serial from datatable union select AccountNumber, Serial2 as Serial from datatable
```

I'm a little rusty at mySQL in particular, but that should give you a general gist.  Then query against it like so:

```
  Select AccountNumber from myView where Serial = (whatever)
```

This is a good workaround if properly normalizing your data is too difficult because of it being tied into other systems/processes.